# Is there any way to return null in JSON_VALUE instead of empty in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-function

My sample code is like this:

```
DECLARE @JsonText varchar(MAX) = '{
    "Test": ""
}'

DECLARE @Name varchar(MAX) = JSON_VALUE(@JsonText, '$.Test') ;

IF (@Name IS NULL)
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Null' AS Result
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
    SELECT 'Empty' AS Result
END
```

and I got an output:

```
Result
----------
Empty
```

My expected output is Null, I have tried with trim and then check string is empty then return null is working fine.

```
IF (@Result = '') 
    SET @Result = NULL;
```

But I am looking for any other alternative if available which returns null instead of empty.

Comment: If you want the value to be `NULL`, then *define* the value as `Null` in your JSON. `Null` and `""` are *not* the same value, just like `NULL` and `''` aren't.

Comment: Can you explain why you want NULL? NULL signifies *unknown* but it's not unknown - it's and empty string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A zero length string (in JSON `""` and in T-SQL `''`) and `NULL` are *not* the same value. In your JSON you have a zero length string. If you want a `NULL` value to be returned from your JSON then define the value as `Null` in your JSON:

```sql
DECLARE @JsonText nvarchar(MAX) = N'{
    "Test": null
}';

DECLARE @Name nvarchar(MAX) = JSON_VALUE(@JsonText, '$.Test');
IF (@Name IS NULL)
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Null' AS Result;
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
    SELECT 'Empty' AS Result;
END;
```

This returns the `varchar` value `'Null'`.

Alternatively, you could use `NULLIF` to return `NULL` if your expression returns a zero length string, but I would suggest that really it's the JSON that needs correcting:

```sql
SET @Name = NULLIF(JSON_VALUE(@JsonText, '$.Test'),N'');
```